# MySQL complex query statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have the following tables:

Regions:

```
Country |  Region
Canada  |  North America
Mexico  |  North America
Germany |  Europe
```

Movies:

```
ID    |  MovieName  | ReleaseDate
1001  |  Star Trek  | 2015-01-01
1002  |  Star Wars  | 2014-06-01
```

Views:

```
ID     |  Country  |  Views
1001   |  Canada   |  50
1001   |  Mexico   |  45
1001   |  Germany  |  125
1002   |  Canada   |  21
1002   |  Germany  |  75
```

The query result I am looking for is something like this:

```
  MovieName   |  North America  |  Europe  |  Total Views |WeeksSinceRelease
    Star Trek |  95             |  125     |  220         |10
    Star Wars |  21             |  75      |  96          |40
```

I am trying to write a prepared statement for a similar problem in Java jdbc for MySQL db.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want us to do your work for you? What have you tried, what are your criteria, what are your indexes on your tables (as in, are all table IDs related?), etc. etc.

Comment: Also `mysql` and `sql` are potentially quite different, what platform are you working on, are you outputting Mysql with PHP? Or something else?

Comment: I'll edit the tags. I am writing a prepared statement for Java jdbc for mysql. The original problem is slightly different but I made up this problem just to learn complex queering.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

```
SELECT Movies.MovieName, 
MAX(IF(Gr.Region='North America', Gr.rViews, 0)) AS `North America`, 
MAX(IF(Gr.Region='Europe', Gr.rViews, 0)) AS `Europe`,
SUM(Gr.rViews) AS `Total Views`,
CEIL(DATEDIFF(NOW(), Movies.ReleaseDate)/7) AS weeks
FROM Movies 
JOIN 
    (SELECT m.ID, r.Region, SUM(v.Views) AS rViews
    FROM Movies m
    JOIN Views v ON m.ID=v.ID
    JOIN Regions r ON v.Country=r.Country
    GROUP BY m.ID, r.Region) Gr ON Movies.ID=Gr.ID
GROUP BY Movies.ID
```

Notes:

- if you add more regions - you will need to create more of `MAX(IF(Gr.Region=[RegionName], Gr.rViews, 0)) AS [RegionName]` in output
- the way you structired - you have to join by string values (Country name) - not a good solution. Think of changing it